# скрыть/показать текст с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, возможно вопрос и глупый но никак не могу понять одну вещь.
вот пример html.

```js
$('#nav_py').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#test').text('TEST');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="animatedBlocks">
    <ul id="navbar">

      <li class="filter active" id="nav_py">
        <h2>Python</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_js">
        <h2>JS and Jquery</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_html">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_css">
        <h2>CSS</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter active" id="nav_qa">
        <h2>QA</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_hobbies">
        <h2>Hobbies</h2>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="center" id="test">
    <p class="tests">text text text text text text text text text
    </p>
  </div>
```

Список который я сделал внутри  отвечает за боковую панель(небольшое меню)
С помощью JQuery я пытаюсь сделать следующее, при наведении курсора мыши на один из

у меня должен меняться текст внутри блока .
Для тренировки я написал немного кода на JS в связке с JQuery.

я понял как благодаря методу text() задавать нужный текст внутри указанного блока, но не нашёл каким методом воспользоваться для смены всего div блока с другим текстом к примеру.

Comment: По сути, то же самое, только используйте `.html()` вместо `.text()`, если я правильно понял. Что означает "смены всего блока"? Вы хотите один блок убрать, а второй поставить на его место, или же просто поменять содержимое блока?

Comment: @MedvedevDev поменять содержимое)

Comment: ну, тогда я вас правильно понял, используйте `.html()`, внутрь которого передаете строку, например с html, что-то типа `$('#test').html('<span>Я ХТМЛ</span>');`

Comment: @MedvedevDev понял спасибо попробую данный метод.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.filter').on('mouseenter', function(){
  var text = $(this).children().text();
   $('#test .tests').text(text);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="animatedBlocks">
        <ul id="navbar">

            <li class="filter active" id="nav_py">
                <h2>Python</h2>
            </li>

            <li class="filter" id="nav_js">
                <h2>JS and Jquery</h2>
            </li>

            <li class="filter" id="nav_html">
                <h2>HTML</h2>
            </li>

            <li class="filter" id="nav_css">
                <h2>CSS</h2>
            </li>

            <li class="filter active" id="nav_qa">
                <h2>QA</h2>
            </li>

            <li class="filter" id="nav_hobbies">
                <h2>Hobbies</h2>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="center" id="test">
        <p class="tests">text text text text text text text text text 
        </p>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле если менять весь контент html то так

```js
$('.filter').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#test').html("<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="animatedBlocks">
    <ul id="navbar">

      <li class="filter active" id="nav_py">
        <h2>Python</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_js">
        <h2>JS and Jquery</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_html">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_css">
        <h2>CSS</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter active" id="nav_qa">
        <h2>QA</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="filter" id="nav_hobbies">
        <h2>Hobbies</h2>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="center" id="test">
    <p class="tests">text text text text text text text text text
    </p>
  </div>
```